# ¿Cómo asignar variable de promesa en mi variable data?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Estoy intentando guardar la URL de una imágen que subo al storage de firebase, pero al momento de asignar la url a mi array 'newWebsite' me sale el siguiente error en la consola del navegador:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'url' of
> undefined

Mi código es el siguiente, (cree una variable fuera del array 'newWebsite' y me asigna sin problemas, pero necesito asignarla en la del arreglo):

````
    firebase: {
        SplashArtCampeones: websiteRef
    },
    data: () => ({
        imagen: null,
        newWebsite: {
            name: '',
            skin: null,
            url: ''
        }
    }),
    methods: {
        clickImage(e) {
            this.imagen = e.target.files[0]
            console.log(this.imagen)
        },
        subirImagen() {
            //Crear referencia de donde quieres subirlo
            new compressor(this.imagen, {
                quality: 0.6,
                success(result) {
                    const refImg = ref.child('SplashArtChamps/'+ result.name)
                    const metadata = { contentType: 'img/jpeg' }
                    refImg.put(result, metadata)
                    .then(data => {
                        data.ref.getDownloadURL()
                        .then(url => {
                            this.newWebsite.url = url          --Aqui asigno la variable url
                        })
                    })
                }
            })
            websiteRef.push(this.newWebsite);
            this.newWebsite.name = '';
            this.newWebsite.skin = null;
            this.newWebsite.url = '';
        },
    }```
````

Comment: el error es simple: Creas newWebsite cuando la promesa se cumple. **bien**. PERO, tratas de usarlo antes de que se cumpla `websiteRef.push(this.newWebsite);` **está fuera del bloque .then** de modo que se ejecuta antes por eso te da error, tratas de usar algo que no existe.

Comment: Aclara el concepto de **[promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** prometido es que va a darse en el futuro **dios sabrá cuando** y las líneas de código fuera del then siguen la ejecución normal de modo que el script pueda terminar y no ponga al sistema a esperar. Aquello que vaya a usar la url debe ir dentro de then o debe ser llamado desde allí.

Comment: Ya corregí lo que me dijiste, pero sigo con el problema. Lo que pasa es que no puedo asignarle ningún valor a mi arreglo this.newWebsite.url dentro del then. Por qué sucede esto ?

Comment: Ya pude solucionar mi problema, muchas gracias !!

Comment: me alegra!! buen día!

Comment: Otra posible solución a tu problema podría ser ocupando callbacks con javascript